# Why HR tag not middle screen on internet explorer and microsoft edge browser

Tags: html, css

I tried to move hr in center screen on internet explorer and microsoft edge but It's moved to right.

*Internet Explorer*

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFpc.png)

*Google Chrome*

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdVkD.png)

*HTML*

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rebeccapurple">
    <hr style="
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
">
</div>
```

Addition to that why scroll showing in internet explorer

Answer (score -1):

Instead of positioning it relative, do it like that:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rebeccapurple">
    <hr style="
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
">
</div>
```

To vertically align you could give the div `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: center`, but generally it's not required to vertically align a hr. Instead give it a margin top and bottom.

Comment: You've removed the vertical alignment

Comment: I've updated my response to include vertical alignment.

Answer (score -1):

You should put into consideration normal transform property (and -ms for old browsers)

```
-moz-transform:    translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform:      translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

and for the scrollbar, try adding

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
overflow-y: hidden;
```

**UPDATE:**
So I did three things:

1. Add overflow:hidden; to the div
2. Change 100vh to 100%
3. Changed left: 50%; to left: 40%;

Comment: So I did three things: 1- add overflow:hidden; to the div
2- change 100vh to 100%
3- changed left: 50%; to left: 40%;